# Need Strategy To Generate Snapshot Of Table Contents After a Series of Random Inserts

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

There are 10 rooms with a set of inventory items. When an item is added/deleted from a room a new row gets inserted to a MS-SQL table. I need the latest update for each room.

Take this series of inserts:

```
 id| room| descriptor1| descriptor2| descriptor3|
 1 | A   | blue       | 2          | large      |
 2 | B   | red        | 1          | small      |
 3 | A   | blue       | 1          | large      |
```

What the resulting table needs to show:

```
room| descriptor1| descriptor2| descriptor3|
A   | blue       |1           | large      |
B   | red        |1           | small      |
```

Ideally, I would write a trigger that would update a room status table. I could then just query the room status table (Select *) to obtain the result. However, this table does not belong to me, I only have read access to a constantly updated table. I need to poll periodically or when I need a report.

How do I do this in MS-SQL? I have some inkling of how I would do it to obtain the status of just one room something like:

```
SELECT descriptor1, descriptor2, descriptor3
FROM myTable mt1
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)
               from myTable mt2
               WHERE room = 'A'    
              );
```

Since I have 10 rooms i would need to do this query 10 times. Can this be narrowed down to a single query? What happens when there are 100 rooms? Is there a better way?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```
SELECT descriptor1, descriptor2, descriptor3
FROM myTable mt1
WHERE id in (SELECT MAX(id)
               From myTable
               Group By room
              );
```

Instead of creating a trigger to update a static table, you should look into creating [a view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).